# Pandas vs list - Speed of changing values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list

In a loop, Why it does take more time changing a pandas column values in comparison to a list? I ran a test:

```
from time import perf_counter
import pandas as pd

example_list = [0 for _ in range(1000000)]
start = perf_counter()
for i in range(1000000):
    example_list[i] = i
end = perf_counter()
print(f"Speed of list: {end-start}")

example_dataframe = pd.DataFrame([0 for _ in range(1000000)])
start = perf_counter()
for i in range(1000000):
    example_dataframe.loc[i, 0] = i
end = perf_counter()
print(f"Speed of dataframe: {end-start}")
```

and the result was:

```
Speed of list: 0.034354630000052566
Speed of dataframe: 21.46266417700008
```

Comment: `my_list` isn’t a list. It’s a Series. Is that actually what you’re doing?

Comment: More importantly, if you need to loop through a pandas dataframe and set individual values, you should probably rethink what you’re trying to accomplish and if there’s a more idiomatic (pandas-native) way to do it of it a DataFrame is ever the right structure for you data.

Comment: Pandas dataframe has lots of functionalities that you can use to ignore using loops, it makes your code more easier to write and increases its readability. In your example, you could easily write : `example_dataframe[0] = range(1000000)`

Comment: my_list was an example. In a real project, I have a csv file with one milion rows, that sometimes data of some columns should be changed in a for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference in performance between modifying values in a list and a DataFrame column is primarily due to the underlying data structures and the overhead associated with DataFrame operations.

When you modify values in a list, you are directly accessing and updating elements in a contiguous block of memory. This operation is efficient because lists are implemented as dynamic arrays in Python, allowing for fast indexing and modification of elements.

On the other hand, when you modify values in a DataFrame column, you are operating on a more complex data structure. DataFrame columns are internally represented as Series objects, which are essentially one-dimensional arrays with additional metadata and index labels. When you modify a value in a DataFrame column, Pandas needs to perform additional checks and operations to maintain the integrity of the DataFrame structure, such as alignment with the index labels and potential resizing of underlying arrays. These additional operations introduce overhead compared to modifying a simple list.

Additionally, accessing and updating individual elements in a DataFrame using `loc` involves more overhead than directly accessing elements in a list due to the indexing and alignment mechanisms used by Pandas.

In your specific test case, modifying values in the list is significantly faster than modifying values in the DataFrame column because of these factors. If you need to perform large-scale element-wise operations or modifications, working with native Python data structures like lists may offer better performance compared to DataFrame operations. However, DataFrame operations provide the benefits of built-in functionality for data manipulation, aggregation, and analysis, which can be more convenient and expressive for many tasks despite the associated overhead.

Comment: "When you modify values in a list, you are directly accessing and updating elements in a contiguous block of memory" that is not true. A list is maintains an array of PyObject pointers. The objects exist on a privately managed heap, not contiguous in memory. Indeed, the data being stored in a continguous block of memory is more likely in a pandas data structure (unless the dtype is `object`, in which case, it is the same as the `list` situation)

Answer (score 3):

The reason pandas is slow for this, is because that's not what it's meant for.

If you're looping through rows and setting individual values, there's often a better way that doesn't involve loops that you write in python.

Let's make your case a little more complicated to show where pandas/numpy excel.

Instead of updating every items, let's check only for even values of the iterator and update those:

```py
from time import perf_counter
import numpy
import pandas

N = int(1e7)
ex_list = [0] * N
ex_df = pandas.DataFrame({"A": [0] * N})

start = perf_counter()
for i in range(N):
    if i % 2:
        ex_list[i] = i
end = perf_counter()
print(f"List: {end - start}")

start = perf_counter()
ex_df = ex_df.assign(B=lambda df: numpy.where(df.index % 2, df.index, 0))
end = perf_counter()
print(f"DataFrame: {end - start}")

assert ex_df["B"].eq(pandas.Series(ex_list)).all()
```

When I run that, the dataframe takes about 1/3 the time of the list:

```
List: 0.651
DataFrame: 0.267
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's correct, but in my project data of a huge panda dataframe should changed one by one based on some calculating and some other data, so I can't use your useful advice.

Comment: @Qeyzho sounds like you need to join some additional data to your dataframe and then do dataframe operations without your loop. You might be surprised what's possible. I recommend asking a more direct question related to your workflow with an example dataframe that includes 10  - 15 rows and 3 - 5 columns

Comment: My question was why it does take more time changing dataframe column values  in a loop comparison to list. As you saied, there are better ways for changing columns values, but maybe I asked my question in wrong way, sory. Thank you, I edited my question.

Comment: @Qeyzho or, *don't use pandas at all*.